# Click on HTML button throw a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, dom, click

I'm quite a JS nob and this might be a very stupid question.

Via the chrome dev tool console, I'm trying to click on a "show more" button that I have on the page I'm visiting (https://www.capterra.com/account-based-marketing-software/):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('Button__CenteredText-sc-2779at-4')[0].click();
```

The click loads more results into the page and that is what I would expect.

However, as soon as the line of code runs, the console throws a:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
at forEach (/directoryPage/assets/webpack:/src/ui/app/gtm-client.js:32)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at initializePayload (/directoryPage/assets/webpack:/src/ui/app/gtm-client.js:31)
at Object.transmitToDataLayer (/directoryPage/assets/webpack:/src/ui/app/gtm-client.js:48)
at /directoryPage/assets/webpack:/src/ui/app/components/PageContainer/LayoutContainer.js:260
```

I have tried to wrap my `click` call around a `try..catch`, but the error keeps popping up.

Does anyone have any idea about the possible cause for this error?

Thanks!
Alessio

Comment: Are you doing this before the DOMContentLoaded event ?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shown in the console seems not to be related to the line of code that you posted. Try to put a breakpoint in the line where `forEach` is executed to see why the value is `null`.

Comment: yeah, you were right. The error is thrown every time you click on the button regardless.